# How can I easily show that string index order when calculating Levenshtein distance don't matter for strings of the same length?

Tags: string, algorithm, levenshtein-distance

When working on my Levenshtein distance implementation I stumbled upon the fact that my indexes were swapped, as shown in this pseudocode (note the `s1[j] == s2[i]` instead of `s1[i] == s2[j]`).

```
L(i, j) = min(L(i - 1, j) + 1,
              L(i, j - 1) + 1,
              L(i - 1, j - 1) + (s1[j] == s2[i] ? 0 : 1))
```

But because my implementation calculates the matrix as a sequence of rectangular submatrixes, it doesn't seem to affect the computation at all, and always yields the correct result, no matter if the indexes are swapped or not. (Or for simplicity just think of the strings as having the same length.)

**Now my question is, how can I prove (not necessarily in a formal way) that the index order doesn't matter for equal length strings?** It seems that because this is the only places that affects the matrix, and because it ends up being symmetrical, swapping the indexes would just transpose the matrix, but I'm not sure if I'm not missing something important.

Comment: `(s[j] == s[i]) == (s[i] == s[j])` is always `true`. You could write a mathematical proof as well but unless I'm missing something I don't think it's necessary.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils is right.  `A == B` if and only if `B == A` (unless you have done operator overloading wrong), so wherever you write one in any program you could *always* write the other instead.  This has nothing to do with Levenshtein distance.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils @j_random_hacker I'm sorry guys, I've been dumb and wrote the code incorrectly. I've updated it to reflect the real algorithm, where it's `s1[i] == s2[j]` and not just `s[i] == s[j]`. The two strings are actually different.

Comment: You are in fact swapping s1 and s2.

Comment: @n.m. : true, so it'll only matter if the strings have different lengths and thus i and j are incorrect initially

Answer (score 0):

As you pointed out, this will only work if the two strings are of equal lengths.

But given a more formal definition of levenshtein in the image below, the only things actually referring to the content of the strings are the function `r(x, y)`. The rest is only concerning the length of the strings, which in this case are the same. So the effect of using `s1[j] == s2[i]` instead of `s1[i] == s2[j]` is the same as swapping the two input parameters `s1` and `s2`.

[image: Levenshtein]

Note: `MSD` = minimum sum of distances